# More efficient way to make many-to-many number matcher

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I have two sets of numbers of differing sizes that I need to run an algorithm to determine if every element in set two can be made up of unique elements from set one, with elements in set one only to be used once.

Example.

Set One: 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 14, 11.
Set Two: 25, 9, 13, 1.

First number to solve is 25, you can add 14 + 11 from set one together. So 25 is a match and you remove 14 and 11 from the first set. You are left with 1, 3, 5, 6, 8.

Next number to solve is 9. 6 + 3 = 9, so you remove 6 and 3 from the first set and set 9 to be matched. You're now left with 1, 5 and 8.

Next number to solve is 13. 5 + 8 = 13. Remove 5 and 8 and you're left with 1.

Next number to solve is 1. Which matches 1 so the last numbers are also solved.

I have written a recursive function to do this, given below. My problem is the performance is too slow - it needs to run as a system test in a few minutes maximum, but it takes much longer than this to solve all paths if you have say 130 elements in set one and 60 elements in set two.

Can anyone suggest a much more efficient and performant way to do this?

```
    foreach (var rhs in rightSideCandidates)
    {
        var matchingSet = GetMatchingSet(rhs, leftSideCandidates.ToArray(), 0, timer);
        if (matchingSet != null && matchingSet.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Matched ({string.Join(",", matchingSet.Select(s => s.Item1))}) to RHS candidate {rhs}");
            matchingSet.ForEach(t => leftSideCandidates.Remove(t));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to find a matching set for rhs {rhs}");
        }
    }

private static (int, LabelledResult)[] GetMatchingSet(RightSideCandidate rhs, (int, LabelledResult)[] leftCandidates, decimal runningAggregation, Stopwatch runTimer)
{
    // Time out if we have been running for a long time as it could potentially go into a deep recursive loop
    if (runTimer.Elapsed.Minutes >= 3)
        Assert.Fail("Matching has been running over 3 minutes so aborting the path discovery and failing the test");

    // If we have no more potential candidates or we have exceeded the sought total, end this branch of the search tree as this is not a solution
    if (leftSideCandidates.Length == 0 || (rhs.Value < 0 && runningAggregation < rhs.Value) || (rhs.Value > 0 && runningAggregation > rhs.Value)) return new (int, LabelledResult)[0];

    foreach (var t in leftSideCandidates)
    {
        // If this node results in a solution, return from here to set off the cascading returns which will carry our solution to the top
        if (t.Item2.Value + runningAggregation == rhs.Value) return new[] { t };

        // Get the new candidate set to pass down to child nodes, without this item in it
        var tmpSet = leftSideCandidates.Where(tc => tc.Item1 != t.Item1).ToArray();
        var pathToResult = GetMatchingSet(rhs, tmpSet, runningAggregation + t.Item2.Value, runTimer);

        // If we have found a path to a solution, then return that child path, adding ourself to it. Otherwise continue with the next possible path
        if (pathToResult.Length > 0)
        {
            return pathToResult.Union(new[] { t }).ToArray();
        }
    }

    // We have run out of potential paths on this route, so return nothing to end discovery of this path
    return new (int, LabelledResult)[0];
}
```

Comment: Looks a question for code review. Also you are a programmer now, i cant suggest enough that if you have a performance problem crack out a benchmarker, and test different approaches

Comment: Can numbers in the set One appear *twice*? E.g. `{1, 5, 5, 20}`? And thus we can have `10 = 5 + 5`, but not `40 = 20 + 20`

Comment: Dmitry - Yes and they can be positive or negative. so on RHS you might have 100, on LHS you have 500 and -400. That is a valid match.

Comment: Any given number can have more than one solution and depending on the chosen solution, following numbers might have a solution or not. Are you supposed to find any solution or the solution that outputs the maximum number of target numbers solved?

Comment: InBetween - For this approach, taking the first match is sufficient, no need to consider alternate combinatoins. If you have a performant idea on how to do the other method then great, but for my needs just taking the first match and moving on is fine

Comment: Also to specify, a number in set 2 can be made up of any number of items from set 1. Ie it is a real edge case but hypothetically, you could have a 100 numbers in set 1 and 1 number in set 2, and every element in set one added together makes the single number in set 2.

Comment: How big can be numbers in set1 and set 2 ? Several hundreds, thousands ? No limit ?

Comment: Tried with linear programming solver but for 140 and 60 items takes too long

Comment: What makes you think that this is doable?  I would be willing to bet money that this is an NP-complete problem.  Therefore it is likely that you either have to settle for an approximate answer, or else accept poor performance.

Comment: Must all numbers in set 1 be used?

Comment: Is it possible that you need to find 5+6+7+8=26?

Comment: How big can be arrays? Do you have limitations by memory?

Comment: @btilly: It is NP-complete. This is a variation of the subset sum problem. However, given that the numbers are small and there are not very many of them, it's likely that there's a pretty efficient solution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem for an overview.

Comment: @EricLippert I am quite familiar with the subset sum problem.  But the usual dynamic programming solution to the subset sum problem doesn't apply as you quickly get into subsets of set 2 that have been partially matched with an open question as to whether you can match the rest.  Even with 60 elements in set 2, keeping track of 60 binary choices is a little much for your average laptop...and the choices for a partial matching state are not just binary.

Comment: @btilly: Yes, that does seem quite difficult. This problem is basically to solve multiple simultaneous interacting subset sum problems.

Comment: @NZJames: Can you say more about why you need to solve this particular problem, and if there are any interesting constraints on the numbers involved?  btilly has convinced me that this problem is in general not solvable quickly, but maybe there is some fact about your problem space that we can exploit to get a good approximate solution.

Comment: Is it always true that number from set Two is a sum of exactly two numbers from set One?